# value of tuple type '(AVAsset?,[ AnyHashable : Any]?)' has no member 'url'

Tags: swift2, swift3, migration

I'm learning Swift3 as I work on migrating code from swift 2.2 to swift 3. I am now stuck on one error and a couple warnings. I need assistance with the error. Trying to access the url value in a type AVAsset. Any assistance or lesson that I can get from this would be greatly appreciated.

```
for index in 0...(assets.count - 1){
   assets[index].fetchAVAssetWithCompleteBlock({ (avAsset) -> Void in
    if let fileURL = avAsset.url{
        let videoData = NSData(contentsOf: fileURL as URL)
        // optionally, write the video to the temp directory
        let videoPath = NSTemporaryDirectory() + "tmpMovie\(index).MOV"
        let videoURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
        let writeResult = videoData?.write(to: videoURL as URL, atomically: true)
        if let writeResult = writeResult, writeResult {
           print("success")
        }
        else {
             print("failure")
        }
         self.arrSelectedGalleryMedia.add(videoURL)
        if self.arrSelectedGalleryMedia.count >= assets.count{
             self.UploadVideo()
        }
     }
   else {
        print("error...!")
     }
   })
}
```

[image]

The error is shown in the picture above

[image]

a different attempt

Comment: `avAsset.0.url`

Comment: Yep, avAsset is a tuple containing an AVAsset and Dictionary

Comment: @luk2302 that didn't work, a similar error pop up "value of tuple type 'AVAsset?' has no member 'url' "

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `AVAsset`? There is no `url` property. `AVURLAsset` has a `url` property.

Comment: @rmaddy I did check it but I saw some reference to URL so I was kinda confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`avAsset` is a tuple to you must access the `AVAsset` object using an index of `0`. Also since it's an optional, you can use flatMap to optionally manipulate it to `videoData`.

```
for (i, dkAsset) in assets.enumerated() {
    dkAsset.fetchAVAssetWithCompleteBlock { avAsset in
        if let data = (avAsset as? AVURLAsset).flatMap({
            NSData(contentsOf: $0.url)
        }) {
            if data.write(
                to: URL(
                    fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + "tmpMovie\(i).MOV"
                ),
                atomically: true
            ) {
                print("success")
            } else {
                print("write failure")
            }
        } else {
            print("cast/read failure")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sill getting the same error. I'll post the screen shot

Comment: You can cast an AVAsset to AVURLAsset, I've updated my answer

Comment: fixing this error produced multiple errors relating to JSON, do you have any insights to this. the issue is in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41757877/use-of-undeclared-type-json-and-use-of-unresolved-identifier-jsonencoding/41759341?noredirect=1#comment70726399_41759341