# Use of undeclared type 'JSON' and use of unresolved identifier 'JSONEncoding'

Tags: json, swift3, swifty-json

I am having the above error on every file in my Xcode 8.2 project (swift 3) that require JSON or JSONEncoding. I already have SwiftyJSON in my pod files and imported it in those files. I already added it in the list of dependancies and links.

[image: Target Dependancies]

[image: link binary]

here's and import example

[image]

and an error example

[image]

Any help to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated

here are more examples from different swift files

this errors says 'Could not infer type for 'arrFeeds''
[image]

this one is for use of undeclared type 'JSON'
[image]

Answer (score 4):

that is Easy.
just do this and Run it...
`import Alamofire`
`import SwiftyJSON`

and 
Replace `JSON?` to `JSON`
that it..

try this
`if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
                success(resJson)
            }
            if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
                failure(error)
}`

Comment: I did that and I get another error 'Variable 'jsonValue' captured by a closure before being initialized ' @ItsMeMihir

Comment: But why you need to store another variable direct pass it

Comment: Yeah, I just saw what you mean. I redeclared the variable jsonValue within the scope of "case .success" that took care of the error

Comment: but I am having the original issue with other swift files with JSON but it not an optional as shown in the above error. I'll update my question

Comment: Now I still have the first errors after changing JSON? to JSON

Comment: try this.......................... `if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = JSON(responseObject.result.value!)
                success(resJson)
            }
            if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
                failure(error)
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133655/discussion-between-kelvin-njeri-and-itsmemihir).